# ROR How to best handle nil in custom validations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this custom validations that throws an "undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass"  when ever birthday is not set because birthday is nil.

```
validate :is_21_or_older 
def is_21_or_older
  if birthday > 21.years.ago.to_date
    errors.add(:birthday, "Must 21 Or Older")
  end
end
```

I already have validates_presence_of for birthday so is there a way to have is_21_or_older called only after validates_presence_of passes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails runs all validators independently, in order to give you an array of all the errors at once. This is done to avoid the all too common scenario:

> Please enter a password.
>
> **`pass`**
>
> The password you have entered is invalid: it does not contain a number.
>
> **`1234`**
>
> The password you have entered is invalid: it does not contain a letter.
>
> **`a1234`**
>
> The password you have entered is invalid: it is not at least six characters long.
>
> **`ab1234`**
>
> The password you have entered is invalid: you cannot use three or more consecutive characters in a sequence.
>
> **`piss off`**
>
> The password you have entered is invalid: it does not contain a number.

There are two things you can do, that I know of. Either include everything under your custom validator, in which case everything is under your control, or use the `:unless => Proc.new { |x| x.birthday.nil? }` modifier to explicitly restrict your validator from running under the circumstances it would break. I'd definitely suggest the first approach; the second is hacky.

```
def is_21_or_older
  if birthday.blank?
    errors.add(:birthday, "Must have birthday")
  elsif birthday > 21.years.ago.to_date
    errors.add(:birthday, "Must 21 Or Older")
  end
end
```

Maybe an even better approach is to keep the presence validator, just exit your custom validator when it sees the other validator's condition is failed.

```
def is_21_or_older
  return true if birthday.blank? # let the other validator handle it

  if birthday > 21.years.ago.to_date
    errors.add(:birthday, "Must 21 Or Older")
  end
end
```